# Why is an analytic function $f:G\rightarrow\mathbb C$ with $0\in G$ identically $0$ if $|f(1/n)|<(\frac12)^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Why is an analytic function $f:G\rightarrow\mathbb C$ with $0\in G$ identically $0$ if $|f(1/n)|<(\frac12)^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$?

I tried assuming that there exists some $p\in\mathbb N$ for which $a_p\ne0$ if we let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ and my idea was to get an arbitrarily small bound on $|a_p|$ to get a contradiction. But that doesn't seem to work or I can't see a step. Can anybody help?

Comment: It is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $G is a connected region

Here $f(0)=0$. Suppose $f$ is not identically zero, then $f$ can be written as $$f(z)=z^k g(z)$$ where $g$ is analytic, $g$ is not a zero function  and $g(0) \neq 0$. Use hypothesis  to arrive a contradiction!

Comment: Assuming $G$ is connected...